# Ignoring autoloader in certain files

Tags: php

I have this function below that autoloads classes before registering them as `new` classes.

```
function __autoload($controller){ 
    $ce = explode('\\', $controller);

    require ROOT . '/app/base/classes/' . 
    end($ce) . '/class.' . 
    end($ce) . '.php';
}
```

How can I ignore this autoloader for one class? The reason behind this is because I installed a package and the class file is another directory to what my class files are in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `require` your package file containing the class you need, before calling `new OneClass()`.

For example, if you have `[ROOT]/app/base/classes/OneClass/class.OneClass.php` alongside with `[ROOT]/app/custom/packages/OneClass.php`, you may:

```
require ROOT . '/app/custom/packages/OneClass.php';

$class = new OneClass(); // will be an instance of /app/custom/packages/OneClass.php
```

But the best solution is using [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php), as described in [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) and [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) recommendations.

And when you use namespaces, and you have correct directory/file structure/names, and you have correctly described namespaces inside your classes:

```
$my_class = new \app\base\OneClass();

// The same class name without any conflicts
$class_from_package = new \app\custom\packages\OneClass();
```

I think it's a more useful approach. You will have some logical directories/files structure which will reflect namespace structure. And if you want load the same class name from other folder, you just will be able to do it by using fully qualified class name with correspond namespace.

It can be a bit weird, to use namespaces, if you did not use them before. You need to support correlations between file path and namespace definition all the time (when moving class file to another folder, for example), but after some time of using it, you will pay no more attention to namespaces than you are paying to tying your shoes before going outdoor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function __autoload($controller){ 

 $ce = explode('\\', $controller);

 $ignore=array('class_1', 'class_2');

 if (!in_array(end($ce), $ignore)) {
  require ROOT . '/app/base/classes/' . 
  end($ce) . '/class.' . 
  end($ce) . '.php';
}
}
```